# Spring не находит CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Впервые пишу на SpringMvc.
Вылетает ошибка:
*org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mkyong.web.EmployeeRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}*

У репозитория стоит аннотация @Repository. Пробовал @Component - та же ошибка.
Что еще можно попробовать?

Модель:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Position;
    
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String string) {
        Name = string;
    }
    
    public String getPosition() {
        return Position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        Position = position;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Id = %s, имя - %s, должность - %s", this.Id, this.Name, this.Position);
    }
}
```

Репо:

```
import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
        List<Employee> findAll();
        List<Employee> findByName(String name);
    }
```

Конфиг с бинами

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.web" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
</beans>
```

Контроллер:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepo repo;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(@PathVariable("name") String name) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("hello");
        model.addObject("msg", name);

        return model;

    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.bytesizebook.com.guide.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springTest</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>5.3.4</spring.version>
        <start-class>common.Application</start-class>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2</version> 
        </dependency> 
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>basic-webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>common.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: А в каком пакете находится бин с репозиторием? По-моему, если указываешь пакет для скана, то он обязательно там должен находиться.

Comment: Он находится в com.mkyong.web, который и в ошибке указан

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос список библиотек из `maven` или `gradle`, которые используете, возможно spring data не добавили?